# Creating a Map on C++ With Arrays & Ascii chars

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, ascii, simulation

I'm trying to create a map on c++, its supposed to be a four way intersection that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYTHA.png

I'm using arrays and ascii for the textures, i'm not allowed to just simply import an image.

Everytime I try I keep getting a gibberish output that looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPRp7.png

Heres my code, does anyone know what im doing wrong?

main.cpp:

```
#include "functions.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

const int ROWS = 47;
const int COLS = 70;

//create an array to represent the map row x cols
int map [ROWS][COLS];

/*green = 2, dark gray=8, light gray=7
*green occupies {1x1:15x23}, {1x48:15x70}, {33x1:47x23}, {33x48:47x70}
*dark gray occuppies{16x1:16x25},{1x24:15x25},{1x46:15x47},{16x46:16x70}, {32x1:32x25},{33x24:47x25},{32x46:32x70},{33x46:47x47}
*light gray occuppies{1x26:47x45},{17x1:31x25},{17x46:31x70}
*/

int green[4][4]={{0,0,14,22},{0,47,14,69}, {32,0,46,22}, {32,47,46,69}};
int dGray[8][4]={{15,0,15,24},{0,23,14,24},{0,45,14,46},{15,45,15,69}, {31,0,31,24},{32,23,46,24},{31,45,31,69},{32,45,46,46}};
int lGray[3][4]={{0,25,46,44},{16,0,30,24},{16,45,30,69}};



//save green to map array
for(int iG=0; iG < 4; iG++){ //loops through the green array with 4 rows
    int sRow=green[iG][0]; //start row
    int fRow=green[iG][2]; //finish row
    int sCol=green[iG][1]; //start col
    int fCol=green[iG][3]; //finish col
    for(int jG=sRow; jG<fRow+1; jG++){
        for(int kG=sCol; kG<fCol+1; kG++){
            map[jG][kG]=2;  
        }
    }
}


//save dGray to map array
for(int idG=0; idG < 8; idG++){ //loops through the green array with 8 rows
    int sRow= dGray[idG][0]; //start row
    int fRow=dGray[idG][2]; //finish row
    int sCol=dGray[idG][1]; //start col
    int fCol=dGray[idG][3]; //finish col
    for(int jdG=sRow; jdG<fRow+1; jdG++){
        for(int kdG=sCol; kdG<fCol+1; kdG++){
            map[jdG][kdG]=8;    
        }
    }
}


//save lGray to map array
for(int ilG=0; ilG < 3; ilG++){ //loops through the green array with 3 rows
    int sRow= lGray[ilG][0]; //start row
    int fRow=lGray[ilG][2]; //finish row
    int sCol=lGray[ilG][1]; //start col
    int fCol=lGray[ilG][3]; //finish col
    for(int jlG=sRow; jlG<fRow+1; jlG++){
        for(int klG=sCol; klG<fCol+1; klG++){
            map[jlG][klG]=7;    
        }
    }
}

    //Loop through the map array and call the coutchar functions with corresponding textures
for(int i=0; i < ROWS; i++){
    for(int j=0; j< COLS; j++){
        //gotoxy(i,j);
        if(map[i][j]==2){ //green grass texture space 219
            coutchar(2,219);
        }else if(map[i][j]==8){ // dark gray curb texture 176
            coutchar(8,176);
        }else if(map[i][j]==7){ // light gray road texture space 219
            coutchar(7,219);
        }
    }
}
```

functions.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
#include <windows.h>
#include "functions.h"

//prints charcters on the screen screen with a given color (Eg: 2 is green)
void coutc(int color, char* output)
{   
    HANDLE handle= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);   
    cout<< output;   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);
}
//prints number on the screen with a given color
void coutc(int color, int output)
{   
    HANDLE handle= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);   
    cout<< output;   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);
}
//prints character based on ASCII code 
void coutchar(int color, int output)
{   
    HANDLE handle= GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);   
    cout<< char(output);   
    SetConsoleTextAttribute( handle, color);
}

//move cursor to location(x, y)
void gotoxy ( short x, short y )
{  
    COORD coord = {x, y};  
    SetConsoleCursorPosition ( GetStdHandle ( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ), coord );
}
```

functions.h:

```
#ifndef FUNCTIONS_H
#define FUNCTIONS_H
//prints charcters on the screen screen with a given color (Eg: 2 is green)
void coutc(int color, char* output);

//prints number on the screen with a given color
void coutc(int color, int output);

//prints character based on ASCII code 
void coutchar(int color, int output);

//move cursor to location(x, y)
void gotoxy ( short x, short y );

#endif
```